# Delete row of an array if an element meets a condition in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have a 2D array of real numbers, I want to eliminate a row if the first element is less than or equal to zero.

Currently I create another array, fill it with elements corresponding to lines in which the first element is positive and deallocate the original array, but it is inefficient since this should be called many times in my program. Also, it doubles the use of memory.

I have looked into the function PACK, but it seems that it gives as a result only 1D vectors. Is there an analogous function that gives a 2D array as a result?

For example, my array could be something like this:

```
0   1.2  5.0
-1. 5.0  2.3
2.3 6.7  0.1
3.5 2.9  0.0
```

And the result should be

```
2.3 6.7  0.1
3.5 2.9  0.0
```

Comment: `reshape(pack(..), shape=[a,b])` gives you a rank-2 array.  However, we really need more detail of exactly what you are trying to manage.

Comment: There will always be some memory duplication, it is virtually unavoidable. No matter whether you allocate by hand or reallocate automatically and no matter whether you copy the data manually or using an intrinsic function. Please show more details, best: show your code.

Comment: Well, you might be able to avoid the overhead by using the same large array all the time but storing your data only in a part of it. But if you need to reallocate the new array to a smaller shape, you have a problem. A pointer to the sub-array might help.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but I think everyone understood this bit. The point is in the actual code implementaion. We really need the code from you, not an example of the array. And we need your requirements. Does the result need to be a contiguous array that encompases the array itself and nothing more?

Comment: @VladimirF I don't think I can share the code, since it is part of a Monte Carlo program. I am not sure how to extract something that can be run...

Comment: @VladimirF Also, the array should simply be similar to the starting array, only shorter.

Comment: As Vladimir F suggests, it's possible to do this manipulation "in place", but to do so you'll have to manage this memory manually instead of using single expressions/intrinsics. You wouldn't be getting good advice showing such an approach, however, if we can't assess your needs correctly: you may want "optimal memory performance", but in many cases what you should really care about is how clear your code is to understand by programmers.

Comment: In this case the code probably does not have to be full and compilable, but we need to know what the result is supposed to be.

Comment: If only Fortran supported (variable sized) collections then this would be trivial. Now the matrix must be converted into a linked list of rows and then re-structured and converted back into a matrix.

Comment: A logical array the same size and shape can often be handy if multiple things need to get performed… and pack, reshape, and many other operation can use that mask.
If it is only needing to happen once, then it may not be worth the elegance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sketch how you can keep the data in place and get a pointer to a  contiguous *n x something* array after deleting a "row". However, that only works if you can make the second index to be the row number.

```
  implicit none
  
  integer, allocatable, target :: a(:,:)
  integer, pointer :: b(:,:)
  integer :: row, rows, iter, n
  real :: x
  
  n = 1000
  
  allocate(a(n,n))
  
  a = 0
  
  rows = n
  do iter = 1, n/2
    call random_number(x)
    
    row = ceiling(x*rows)
    
    a(:,row:rows-1) = a(:,row+1:rows)
    rows = rows - 1
    
    b => a(:,1:rows)
    
    print *,size(b,1), size(b,2), is_contiguous(b)
    
  end do
end
```

If you need the row index to be the first index, it will work as well, but the resulting pointer won't be contiguous.

```
  ...
  do iter = 1, n/2
    call random_number(x)
    
    row = ceiling(x*rows)
    
    a(row:rows-1,:) = a(row+1:rows,:)
    rows = rows - 1
    
    b => a(1:rows,:)
    
    print *,size(b,1), size(b,2), is_contiguous(b)
    
  end do
end
```

---

If you need `a` to be truly reallocated, it won't be possible without a temporary array. If you want to avoid the compiler allocating a new temporary each time, you can use a fixed one manually. The compiler is likely to be re-use the space already being occupied by `a` (loc does not change), but it will cost some significant speed time anyway:

```
  implicit none
  
  integer, allocatable :: a(:,:), tmp(:,:)
  integer :: row, rows, iter, n
  real :: x
  
  n = 1000
  
  allocate(a(n,n), tmp(n,n))
  
  a = 0
  tmp = a
  
  rows = n
  do iter = 1, n/2
    call random_number(x)
    
    row = ceiling(x*rows)
    
    tmp(row:rows-1,:) = a(row+1:rows,:)
    rows = rows - 1
    
    a = tmp(1:rows,:)
    
    print *,size(a,1), size(a,2), loc(a)
    
  end do
end
```

---

Maybe my code will fail for x = 0, but I ignore this digression for simplicity.